# C++ Vowels in string, comparison forbidden

Tags: c++

I'm trying to count the total number of vowels in a string. I'm using strlen to get the total length of the string but then when I try and count through the string by each letter it says C++ forbids comparison. So I assume something is wrong in my if statement.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    char sentence[] = "";
    int count;
    int total;
    int length;
    int lengthcount;
    int output;
    output = 0;
    length = 0;
    count = 0;
    total = 0;
    cin >> total;

    while (total != count){
        cin >> sentence;
        length = strlen(sentence);
        while (length != lengthcount)
            if (sentence[length] == "a" ||sentence[length] == "e"||sentence[length] == "i"||sentence[length] == "o"||sentence[length] == "u"||sentence[length] == "y"){
             ++ output;
             ++ lengthcount;
                 else{
                ++lengthcount;
             }
            }
        ++count;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (sentence[length] == 'a'...`

Comment: Also, you have undefined behaviour when you read into `sentence`, which is a `char[1]`.

Comment: `char sentence[] = "";` creates an array of size one, into which a single `NUL`/`'\0'` is copied.  It is not big enough to accept arbitrary input at `cin >> sentence`, and you have consequent undefined behaviour.  It may be best to input into a `std::string`.  Further, try to get in the habit of coding `if (std::cin >> somevar)` ...use somevar... `else` ...handle error of not getting somevar value...

Comment: Aside from using the wrong literal type, your first compare will be checking the null terminator of the string and hence is wasted motion.

Comment: `lengthCount` is uninitialized.  `length` is never incremented or decremented, but is used to index the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sentence[length]` is a single character. It should be compared to a `'a'` and not `"a"`.

`"a"` is a character array and direct comparison with the built in `operator==` is not supported.

```
sentence[index] == 'a'; // where index is probably lengthcount in your example
```

Should do the trick. If use of `std::string` is an option, you should favour that over `char` arrays.

In addition, your `char sentence[] = "";` will need some more space than just the `'\0'` character. Some alternatives include the use of `std::string` and `std::getline` or `char[nnn]` with `cin.get(...)` to make sure that you don't overrun the buffer you allocate.

Comment: Thank you, the code compiles now and I've added `cout << output` but the output is always 0, it's not increasing the output for some reason. I also followed your advice and I'm now using `string`

Comment: Note there is UB because `sentence` is a `char[1]`.

Answer (score 2):

See Nialls answer for one of the main problems.

The algorithmic problem with your code is again in the `if` statement.

`sentence[length]` returns the last character of your c_string (in this case, the null character `'/0'` that terminates the string).

Your if statement should look more like:

```
if (sentence[lengthcount] == 'a'\
  ||sentence[lengthcount] == 'e'\
  ||sentence[lengthcount] == 'i'\
  ||sentence[lengthcount] == 'o'\
  ||sentence[lengthcount] == 'u'\
  ||sentence[lengthcount] == 'y')
{
    \\do something
}
```

Please remember to pre-allocate space for the string too, i.e.

```
char sentence[50];
```

which would give you space for 49 chars + terminator.
Alternatively, use a `std::string`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to count the total number of vowels in the given string, you need to use `sentence[lengthcount]`. Lets say the `sentence` is `abc` `strlen(sentence)` would return 3, and since in c++, the indexing begins with 0 and not 1, therefore sentence[length] would check for '\0' hence in the entire loop you check against the last value which is '\0' which is meaningless. Also, don't forget to initialize lengthcount. Rest all the things per-mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

char sentence [] = "" produces an array sentence with a length of 1.

cin >> sentence isn't going to work very well, is it, if sentence cannot hold more than one character and one character is already needed for the trailing nul byte?

lengthcount is an unitialised variable, and the rest of the code just makes my head hurt.